# Need help moving a hyperlinked image in CSS

Tags: html, css

So i have 2 images, an icon for Facebook, and one for Twitter retrieved from FontAwesome. I have the code and everything but for the life of me can't get it moved how I want it on the page. Help??

Here's my HTML

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .large {
        font-size: 4cm;
    }

    .blue {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square large blue"></i></a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square large blue"></i></a>
```

Here's my CSS I've been fiddling with

```
    facebook-square {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    twitter-square {
        margin-left: 170px;
    }
```

Comment: may be you have a wrong class selector, you have to put a dot before class name

Answer (score 0):

You could try using position: relative

```
facebook-square {
        position: relative;
        left:20px;
    }
twitter-square {
        position: relative;
        left:170px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if you just simplified the CSS, in which case disregard this answer, but the selector needs to be `.fa-facebook-square` and `.fa-twitter-square`, not `facebook-square` and `twitter-square` in order to match with your classes in the html tags.

And as mentioned in the previous answer, you do need to set `position` to something first in order to move elements. [See the MDN Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

may be you have a problem on class selector becuase to select elements with a specific class, you have to write a period (.) character, followed by the name of the class.
In your case it should be as below

```
.fa-facebook-square {
        position: relative;
        left:20px;
    }
.fa-twitter-square {
        position: relative;
        left:170px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those selectors to your html tags `.fa-facebook-square` and `.fa-twitter-square`, not **facebook-square** and **twitter-square** in order to match with your classes in your css